# The route that leads you to the index page is not going to the controller first

Tags: php, laravel

I apologize for my bad English. My problem is that the route that leads to the index page is not going to the controller first. I am getting an error that is telling me the pictures variable is undefined. Here is my code for the route:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');





Route::get('event', 'EventsController@index');

Route::get('video', 'VideosController@index');

Route::get('about', function() {
    return view('about.about');
});

//Gallery routes
Route::get('gallery', 'PictureController@index');
Route::get('gallery/{picture}', 'PictureController@show');
Route::get('createPicture', 'PictureController@create');
Route::post('PictureStored', 'PictureController@store');
Route::delete('gallery/{picture}', 'PictureController@destroy');
Route::get('gallery/{picture}/edit', 'PictureController@edit');
Route::patch('gallery/{picture}', 'PictureController@update');


//Route::get('gallery/{picture}/comment/create', 'CommentsController@create');
Route::post('gallery/{picture}/comment', 'CommentsController@store')->name('comments.stored');
Route::delete('/comments/{comment}','CommentsController@destroy')->name('comments.destroyed');
//Route::resource('admin/comments','Admin\CommentsController');

//Videos routes
Route::get('video', 'VideosController@index');
Route::get('createVideo', 'VideosController@create');
Route::post('VideoStored', 'VideosController@store');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('admin/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
Route::get('admin', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm');

Route::get('/admin-login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin-login', 'Admin\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/admin-password/email', 'Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail ')->name('admin.password.email');
Route::get('admin-password/reset','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('admin-password/reset','Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset ');
Route::get('admin-password/reset/{token}','Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm ');



//Events
Route::get('/event','EventsController@index');
Route::resource('admin/events','Admin\EventsController');

// Admin videos
Route::resource('admin/videos','Admin\VideosController');

//Admin Gallery
Route::resource('admin/pictures','Admin\PicturesController');

// Admin comment
Route::resource('admin/comments','Admin\CommentsController');
```

Just in case I will show you guys my HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $pictures = Picture::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(3);

    //Picture::latest()->get();
    return view('home.home', compact("pictures"));
}
```

Here is my view for the home.blade.php:

```
<!-- Banner -->
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="inner">
                <h1>Deanna Belton Art</h1>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- gallery -->
        <section id="galleries">

            <!-- Photo Posts -->
            <div class="gallery">
                <header class="special">
                    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="content">
                    <!--show the most recent posts-->
                    @foreach($pictures as $picture)
                        <div class="media {{$picture->tag }}">
                            <a href="{{"gallery/" . $picture->id}}" class="image">
                                <img class="pictures" src="./storage/app/{{$picture->picture}}" alt="" title="{{$picture->title}}" />
                            </a>
                            <h3 style="text-align: center;">{{$picture->title}}</h3>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach


                </div>
                <footer>
                    <a href="{{url('/gallery')}}" class="button big">All Pictures</a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Someone requested to see the route:list. Here it is:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name                 | Action                                                                  | Middleware      |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                             |                      | Closure                                                                 | web             |
|        | POST      | PictureStored                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@store                            | web             |
|        | POST      | VideoStored                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@store                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | about                         |                      | Closure                                                                 | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-login                   | admin.login          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-login                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@login                        | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-password/email          | admin.password.email | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-password/reset          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-password/reset          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-password/reset/{token}  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin/comments                | comments.store       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@store                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments                | comments.index       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@index                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/create         | comments.create      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@create                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@show                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@destroy                   | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@update                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/{comment}/edit | comments.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@edit                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events                  | events.index         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@index                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/events                  | events.store         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@store                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/create           | events.create        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@create                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/events/{event}          | events.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@destroy                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/events/{event}          | events.update        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@update                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/{event}          | events.show          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@show                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/{event}/edit     | events.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@edit                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/home                    |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@index                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures                | pictures.index       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@index                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/pictures                | pictures.store       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@store                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/create         | pictures.create      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@create                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@destroy                   | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@update                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@show                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/{picture}/edit | pictures.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@edit                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/videos                  | videos.store         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@store                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos                  | videos.index         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@index                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/create           | videos.create        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@create                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.update        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@update                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.show          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@show                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@destroy                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/{video}/edit     | videos.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@edit                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                      |                      | Closure                                                                 | api,auth:api    |
|        | DELETE    | comments/{comment}            | comments.destroyed   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy                         | web,auth:web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | createPicture                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@create                           | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | createVideo                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@create                            | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | event                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@index                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery                       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@index                            | web             |
|        | DELETE    | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@destroy                          | web             |
|        | PATCH     | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@update                           | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@show                             | web             |
|        | POST      | gallery/{picture}/comment     | comments.stored      | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store                           | web,auth:web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery/{picture}/edit        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@edit                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                               | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                         | login                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                 | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | login                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                         | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | logout                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                        | web             |
|        | POST      | password/email                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail   | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm  | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | password/reset                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                 | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm         | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | register                      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                   | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm       | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | video                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@index                             | web             |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
[chameleon@php laravelProject]$ php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name                 | Action                                                                  | Middleware      |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                             |                      | Closure                                                                 | web             |
|        | POST      | PictureStored                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@store                            | web             |
|        | POST      | VideoStored                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@store                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | about                         |                      | Closure                                                                 | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-login                   | admin.login          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-login                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@login                        | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-password/email          | admin.password.email | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin-password/reset          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-password/reset          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin-password/reset/{token}  |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest:admin |
|        | POST      | admin/comments                | comments.store       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@store                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments                | comments.index       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@index                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/create         | comments.create      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@create                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@show                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@destroy                   | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/comments/{comment}      | comments.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@update                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/comments/{comment}/edit | comments.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CommentsController@edit                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events                  | events.index         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@index                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/events                  | events.store         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@store                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/create           | events.create        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@create                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/events/{event}          | events.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@destroy                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/events/{event}          | events.update        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@update                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/{event}          | events.show          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@show                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/events/{event}/edit     | events.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\EventsController@edit                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/home                    |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@index                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures                | pictures.index       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@index                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/pictures                | pictures.store       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@store                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/create         | pictures.create      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@create                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@destroy                   | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@update                    | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/{picture}      | pictures.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@show                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/pictures/{picture}/edit | pictures.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PicturesController@edit                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | POST      | admin/videos                  | videos.store         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@store                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos                  | videos.index         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@index                       | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/create           | videos.create        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@create                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.update        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@update                      | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.show          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@show                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/videos/{video}          | videos.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@destroy                     | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/videos/{video}/edit     | videos.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\VideosController@edit                        | web,auth:admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                      |                      | Closure                                                                 | api,auth:api    |
|        | DELETE    | comments/{comment}            | comments.destroyed   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy                         | web,auth:web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | createPicture                 |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@create                           | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | createVideo                   |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@create                            | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | event                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@index                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery                       |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@index                            | web             |
|        | DELETE    | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@destroy                          | web             |
|        | PATCH     | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@update                           | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery/{picture}             |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@show                             | web             |
|        | POST      | gallery/{picture}/comment     | comments.stored      | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store                           | web,auth:web    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | gallery/{picture}/edit        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\PictureController@edit                             | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                               | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                         | login                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                 | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | login                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                         | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | logout                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                        | web             |
|        | POST      | password/email                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail   | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm  | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | password/reset                |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                 | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm         | web,guest       |
|        | POST      | register                      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                   | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                      |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm       | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | video                         |                      | App\Http\Controllers\VideosController@index                             | web             |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Check on top of routes/web.php if the standard '/' from the laravel install is still there. The first route laravel finds will be handled as such. Or run php artisan route:list and see what rolling out. If it's not obvious, post the answer of route:list in your question.

Comment: Its not there and the route:list shows its a closure action. I made sure I commented it out the laravel install standard route. I will update my post for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm was not uploading for some reason.....
I hate PHPStorm and its glitches.

Comment: PHPstorm doesn't automatically upload by default, keep that setting. I've created a shortcut 'Control+Shift+o' (o as in Oscar). Or use version control. And use the 'barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper' package. Read the instructions at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper